# Error message when saving file refering to grasswald addon

Tags: add-on, error, system, saving

I'm receiving an error message when I save my blend file. The strange thing about it is that the message refers to an addon which I did not even use in the project. The file seems to save just fine, but still, it makes me a little nervous. Thanks for your help.

[image: Error Message]

```
Read prefs: C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\3.0\config\userpref.blend
cmolcore imported with success! v1.12
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 3.0\3.0\scripts\modules\addon_utils.py", line 351, in enable
    mod = __import__(module_name)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'render_auto_tile_size'
GRASWALD INFO: Registering scatter plugin: Graswald Internal
GRASWALD ERROR<{code.co_name} in {code.co_filename}:{code.co_firstlineno}>: Failed to read news. <urlopen error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: certificate has expired (_ssl.c:1129)>
GRASWALD WARNGING: You must enable the copy attributes addon use the CTRL+C graswald > copy to clipboard
GRASWALD INFO: Reading blend: Graswald Pro (1, 3, 12), blend (1, 3, 12), blender (3, 0, 1)
GRASWALD INFO: FILE UP TO DATE
Writing userprefs: 'C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\3.0\config\userpref.blend' ok
Info: Preferences saved
Writing userprefs: 'C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\3.0\config\userpref.blend' ok
Info: Preferences saved
Writing userprefs: 'C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\3.0\config\userpref.blend' ok
Info: Preferences saved
Writing userprefs: 'C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\3.0\config\userpref.blend' ok
Info: Preferences saved
Writing userprefs: 'C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\3.0\config\userpref.blend' ok
Info: Preferences saved
Writing userprefs: 'C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\3.0\config\userpref.blend' ok
Info: Preferences saved
Writing userprefs: 'C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\3.0\config\userpref.blend' ok
Info: Preferences saved
Writing userprefs: 'C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\3.0\config\userpref.blend' ok
Info: Preferences saved
Writing userprefs: 'C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\3.0\config\userpref.blend' ok
Info: Preferences saved
Writing userprefs: 'C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\3.0\config\userpref.blend' ok
Info: Preferences saved
Writing userprefs: 'C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\3.0\config\userpref.blend' ok
Info: Preferences saved
Read blend: F:\Unsere_Daten_Chri\Kreation\Bundesforste\Sieben Thesen\Produktion\BioOekonomie\Bl_BO\Szenen_BO\T-Rex\T-Rex3.blend
Info: Read library:  'F:\Unsere_Daten_Chri\Kreation\Bundesforste\Sieben Thesen\Produktion\Luft\Bl_Luft\Links_Luft\Pflanze\Pflanze4.blend', '//..\..\..\..\Luft\Bl_Luft\Links_Luft\Pflanze\Pflanze4.blend', parent '<direct>'
GRASWALD INFO: Reading blend: Graswald Pro (1, 3, 12), blend (1, 3, 12), blender (3, 0, 1)
GRASWALD INFO: FILE UP TO DATE
Writing userprefs: 'C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\3.0\config\userpref.blend' ok
Info: Preferences saved
Writing userprefs: 'C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\3.0\config\userpref.blend' ok
Info: Preferences saved
Writing userprefs: 'C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\3.0\config\userpref.blend' ok
Info: Preferences saved
Writing userprefs: 'C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\3.0\config\userpref.blend' ok
Info: Preferences saved
Writing userprefs: 'C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\3.0\config\userpref.blend' ok
Info: Preferences saved
Writing userprefs: 'C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\3.0\config\userpref.blend' ok
Info: Preferences saved
Writing userprefs: 'C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\3.0\config\userpref.blend' ok
Info: Preferences saved
Writing userprefs: 'C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\3.0\config\userpref.blend' ok
Info: Preferences saved
Writing userprefs: 'C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\3.0\config\userpref.blend' ok
Info: Preferences saved
Writing userprefs: 'C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\3.0\config\userpref.blend' ok
Info: Preferences saved
Writing userprefs: 'C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\3.0\config\userpref.blend' ok
Info: Preferences saved
Info: Read library:  'F:\Unsere_Daten_Chri\Kreation\Bundesforste\Sieben Thesen\Produktion\Luft\Bl_Luft\Links_Luft\Pflanze\Pflanze4.blend', '//..\..\..\..\Luft\Bl_Luft\Links_Luft\Pflanze\Pflanze4.blend', parent '<direct>'

GRASWALD INFO: Purging unused data
materials

collections

materials

collections

Info: Saved "T-Rex3.blend"

GRASWALD INFO: Purging unused data
materials

collections

materials

collections

Info: Saved "T-Rex3.blend"

GRASWALD INFO: Purging unused data
materials

collections

materials

collections

Info: Saved "T-Rex3.blend"

GRASWALD INFO: Purging unused data
materials

collections

materials

collections

Info: Saved "T-Rex3.blend"

Python: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\3.0\scripts\addons\Graswald-Pro\simulation\ui\__init__.py", line 32, in poll
    return len(graswald.gsystems) and graswald.active.get_gsettings(context)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\3.0\scripts\addons\Graswald-Pro\core\data\gsystem.py", line 103, in get_gsettings
    context.scene.graswald.gsettings[self.gsettings_id_int]
KeyError: 'bpy_prop_collection[key]: key "17" not found'

location: <unknown location>:-1
Python: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\3.0\scripts\addons\Graswald-Pro\core\ui\materials.py", line 58, in poll
    return len(graswald.gsystems) and graswald.active.get_gsettings(context)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\3.0\scripts\addons\Graswald-Pro\core\data\gsystem.py", line 103, in get_gsettings
    context.scene.graswald.gsettings[self.gsettings_id_int]
KeyError: 'bpy_prop_collection[key]: key "17" not found'

location: <unknown location>:-1
Python: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\3.0\scripts\addons\Graswald-Pro\core\ui\systems.py", line 375, in poll
    return len(graswald.gsystems) and graswald.active.get_gsettings(context)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\3.0\scripts\addons\Graswald-Pro\core\data\gsystem.py", line 103, in get_gsettings
    context.scene.graswald.gsettings[self.gsettings_id_int]
KeyError: 'bpy_prop_collection[key]: key "17" not found'

location: <unknown location>:-1
Python: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\3.0\scripts\addons\Graswald-Pro\core\ui\systems.py", line 324, in poll
    return len(graswald.gsystems) and graswald.active.get_gsettings(context)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\3.0\scripts\addons\Graswald-Pro\core\data\gsystem.py", line 103, in get_gsettings
    context.scene.graswald.gsettings[self.gsettings_id_int]
KeyError: 'bpy_prop_collection[key]: key "17" not found'

location: <unknown location>:-1
Python: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\3.0\scripts\addons\Graswald-Pro\simulation\ui\__init__.py", line 32, in poll
    return len(graswald.gsystems) and graswald.active.get_gsettings(context)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\3.0\scripts\addons\Graswald-Pro\core\data\gsystem.py", line 103, in get_gsettings
    context.scene.graswald.gsettings[self.gsettings_id_int]
KeyError: 'bpy_prop_collection[key]: key "17" not found'

location: <unknown location>:-1
Python: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\3.0\scripts\addons\Graswald-Pro\core\ui\materials.py", line 58, in poll
    return len(graswald.gsystems) and graswald.active.get_gsettings(context)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\3.0\scripts\addons\Graswald-Pro\core\data\gsystem.py", line 103, in get_gsettings
    context.scene.graswald.gsettings[self.gsettings_id_int]
KeyError: 'bpy_prop_collection[key]: key "17" not found'

location: <unknown location>:-1
Python: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\3.0\scripts\addons\Graswald-Pro\core\ui\systems.py", line 375, in poll
    return len(graswald.gsystems) and graswald.active.get_gsettings(context)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\3.0\scripts\addons\Graswald-Pro\core\data\gsystem.py", line 103, in get_gsettings
    context.scene.graswald.gsettings[self.gsettings_id_int]
KeyError: 'bpy_prop_collection[key]: key "17" not found'

location: <unknown location>:-1
Python: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\3.0\scripts\addons\Graswald-Pro\core\ui\systems.py", line 324, in poll
    return len(graswald.gsystems) and graswald.active.get_gsettings(context)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\3.0\scripts\addons\Graswald-Pro\core\data\gsystem.py", line 103, in get_gsettings
    context.scene.graswald.gsettings[self.gsettings_id_int]
KeyError: 'bpy_prop_collection[key]: key "17" not found'

location: <unknown location>:-1
GRASWALD INFO: Purging unused data
materials

collections

materials

collections

Info: Saved "T-Rex3.blend"

Python: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\3.0\scripts\addons\Graswald-Pro\simulation\ui\__init__.py", line 32, in poll
    return len(graswald.gsystems) and graswald.active.get_gsettings(context)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\3.0\scripts\addons\Graswald-Pro\core\data\gsystem.py", line 103, in get_gsettings
    context.scene.graswald.gsettings[self.gsettings_id_int]
KeyError: 'bpy_prop_collection[key]: key "17" not found'

location: <unknown location>:-1
Python: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\3.0\scripts\addons\Graswald-Pro\core\ui\materials.py", line 58, in poll
    return len(graswald.gsystems) and graswald.active.get_gsettings(context)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\3.0\scripts\addons\Graswald-Pro\core\data\gsystem.py", line 103, in get_gsettings
    context.scene.graswald.gsettings[self.gsettings_id_int]
KeyError: 'bpy_prop_collection[key]: key "17" not found'

location: <unknown location>:-1
Python: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\3.0\scripts\addons\Graswald-Pro\core\ui\systems.py", line 375, in poll
    return len(graswald.gsystems) and graswald.active.get_gsettings(context)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\3.0\scripts\addons\Graswald-Pro\core\data\gsystem.py", line 103, in get_gsettings
    context.scene.graswald.gsettings[self.gsettings_id_int]
KeyError: 'bpy_prop_collection[key]: key "17" not found'

location: <unknown location>:-1
Python: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\3.0\scripts\addons\Graswald-Pro\core\ui\systems.py", line 324, in poll
    return len(graswald.gsystems) and graswald.active.get_gsettings(context)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\3.0\scripts\addons\Graswald-Pro\core\data\gsystem.py", line 103, in get_gsettings
    context.scene.graswald.gsettings[self.gsettings_id_int]
KeyError: 'bpy_prop_collection[key]: key "17" not found'

location: <unknown location>:-1
Python: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\3.0\scripts\addons\Graswald-Pro\simulation\ui\__init__.py", line 32, in poll
    return len(graswald.gsystems) and graswald.active.get_gsettings(context)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\3.0\scripts\addons\Graswald-Pro\core\data\gsystem.py", line 103, in get_gsettings
    context.scene.graswald.gsettings[self.gsettings_id_int]
KeyError: 'bpy_prop_collection[key]: key "17" not found'

location: <unknown location>:-1
Python: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\3.0\scripts\addons\Graswald-Pro\core\ui\materials.py", line 58, in poll
    return len(graswald.gsystems) and graswald.active.get_gsettings(context)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\3.0\scripts\addons\Graswald-Pro\core\data\gsystem.py", line 103, in get_gsettings
    context.scene.graswald.gsettings[self.gsettings_id_int]
KeyError: 'bpy_prop_collection[key]: key "17" not found'

location: <unknown location>:-1
Python: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\3.0\scripts\addons\Graswald-Pro\core\ui\systems.py", line 375, in poll
    return len(graswald.gsystems) and graswald.active.get_gsettings(context)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\3.0\scripts\addons\Graswald-Pro\core\data\gsystem.py", line 103, in get_gsettings
    context.scene.graswald.gsettings[self.gsettings_id_int]
KeyError: 'bpy_prop_collection[key]: key "17" not found'

location: <unknown location>:-1
Python: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\3.0\scripts\addons\Graswald-Pro\core\ui\systems.py", line 324, in poll
    return len(graswald.gsystems) and graswald.active.get_gsettings(context)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\3.0\scripts\addons\Graswald-Pro\core\data\gsystem.py", line 103, in get_gsettings
    context.scene.graswald.gsettings[self.gsettings_id_int]
KeyError: 'bpy_prop_collection[key]: key "17" not found'

location: <unknown location>:-1
Python: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\3.0\scripts\addons\Graswald-Pro\simulation\ui\__init__.py", line 32, in poll
    return len(graswald.gsystems) and graswald.active.get_gsettings(context)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\3.0\scripts\addons\Graswald-Pro\core\data\gsystem.py", line 103, in get_gsettings
    context.scene.graswald.gsettings[self.gsettings_id_int]
KeyError: 'bpy_prop_collection[key]: key "17" not found'

location: <unknown location>:-1
Python: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\3.0\scripts\addons\Graswald-Pro\core\ui\materials.py", line 58, in poll
    return len(graswald.gsystems) and graswald.active.get_gsettings(context)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\3.0\scripts\addons\Graswald-Pro\core\data\gsystem.py", line 103, in get_gsettings
    context.scene.graswald.gsettings[self.gsettings_id_int]
KeyError: 'bpy_prop_collection[key]: key "17" not found'

location: <unknown location>:-1
Python: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\3.0\scripts\addons\Graswald-Pro\core\ui\systems.py", line 375, in poll
    return len(graswald.gsystems) and graswald.active.get_gsettings(context)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\3.0\scripts\addons\Graswald-Pro\core\data\gsystem.py", line 103, in get_gsettings
    context.scene.graswald.gsettings[self.gsettings_id_int]
KeyError: 'bpy_prop_collection[key]: key "17" not found'

location: <unknown location>:-1
Python: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\3.0\scripts\addons\Graswald-Pro\core\ui\systems.py", line 324, in poll
    return len(graswald.gsystems) and graswald.active.get_gsettings(context)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\3.0\scripts\addons\Graswald-Pro\core\data\gsystem.py", line 103, in get_gsettings
    context.scene.graswald.gsettings[self.gsettings_id_int]
KeyError: 'bpy_prop_collection[key]: key "17" not found'

location: <unknown location>:-1
Python: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\3.0\scripts\addons\Graswald-Pro\simulation\ui\__init__.py", line 32, in poll
    return len(graswald.gsystems) and graswald.active.get_gsettings(context)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\3.0\scripts\addons\Graswald-Pro\core\data\gsystem.py", line 103, in get_gsettings
    context.scene.graswald.gsettings[self.gsettings_id_int]
KeyError: 'bpy_prop_collection[key]: key "17" not found'

location: <unknown location>:-1
Python: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\3.0\scripts\addons\Graswald-Pro\core\ui\materials.py", line 58, in poll
    return len(graswald.gsystems) and graswald.active.get_gsettings(context)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\3.0\scripts\addons\Graswald-Pro\core\data\gsystem.py", line 103, in get_gsettings
    context.scene.graswald.gsettings[self.gsettings_id_int]
KeyError: 'bpy_prop_collection[key]: key "17" not found'

location: <unknown location>:-1
Python: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\3.0\scripts\addons\Graswald-Pro\core\ui\systems.py", line 375, in poll
    return len(graswald.gsystems) and graswald.active.get_gsettings(context)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\3.0\scripts\addons\Graswald-Pro\core\data\gsystem.py", line 103, in get_gsettings
    context.scene.graswald.gsettings[self.gsettings_id_int]
KeyError: 'bpy_prop_collection[key]: key "17" not found'

location: <unknown location>:-1
Python: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\3.0\scripts\addons\Graswald-Pro\core\ui\systems.py", line 324, in poll
    return len(graswald.gsystems) and graswald.active.get_gsettings(context)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\3.0\scripts\addons\Graswald-Pro\core\data\gsystem.py", line 103, in get_gsettings
    context.scene.graswald.gsettings[self.gsettings_id_int]
KeyError: 'bpy_prop_collection[key]: key "17" not found'

location: <unknown location>:-1
Python: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\3.0\scripts\addons\Graswald-Pro\simulation\ui\__init__.py", line 32, in poll
    return len(graswald.gsystems) and graswald.active.get_gsettings(context)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\3.0\scripts\addons\Graswald-Pro\core\data\gsystem.py", line 103, in get_gsettings
    context.scene.graswald.gsettings[self.gsettings_id_int]
KeyError: 'bpy_prop_collection[key]: key "17" not found'

location: <unknown location>:-1
Python: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\3.0\scripts\addons\Graswald-Pro\core\ui\materials.py", line 58, in poll
    return len(graswald.gsystems) and graswald.active.get_gsettings(context)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\3.0\scripts\addons\Graswald-Pro\core\data\gsystem.py", line 103, in get_gsettings
    context.scene.graswald.gsettings[self.gsettings_id_int]
KeyError: 'bpy_prop_collection[key]: key "17" not found'

location: <unknown location>:-1
Python: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\3.0\scripts\addons\Graswald-Pro\core\ui\systems.py", line 375, in poll
    return len(graswald.gsystems) and graswald.active.get_gsettings(context)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\3.0\scripts\addons\Graswald-Pro\core\data\gsystem.py", line 103, in get_gsettings
    context.scene.graswald.gsettings[self.gsettings_id_int]
KeyError: 'bpy_prop_collection[key]: key "17" not found'

location: <unknown location>:-1
Python: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\3.0\scripts\addons\Graswald-Pro\core\ui\systems.py", line 324, in poll
    return len(graswald.gsystems) and graswald.active.get_gsettings(context)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\3.0\scripts\addons\Graswald-Pro\core\data\gsystem.py", line 103, in get_gsettings
    context.scene.graswald.gsettings[self.gsettings_id_int]
KeyError: 'bpy_prop_collection[key]: key "17" not found'

location: <unknown location>:-1
Python: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\3.0\scripts\addons\Graswald-Pro\simulation\ui\__init__.py", line 32, in poll
    return len(graswald.gsystems) and graswald.active.get_gsettings(context)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\3.0\scripts\addons\Graswald-Pro\core\data\gsystem.py", line 103, in get_gsettings
    context.scene.graswald.gsettings[self.gsettings_id_int]
KeyError: 'bpy_prop_collection[key]: key "17" not found'

location: <unknown location>:-1
Python: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\3.0\scripts\addons\Graswald-Pro\core\ui\materials.py", line 58, in poll
    return len(graswald.gsystems) and graswald.active.get_gsettings(context)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\3.0\scripts\addons\Graswald-Pro\core\data\gsystem.py", line 103, in get_gsettings
    context.scene.graswald.gsettings[self.gsettings_id_int]
KeyError: 'bpy_prop_collection[key]: key "17" not found'

location: <unknown location>:-1
Python: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\3.0\scripts\addons\Graswald-Pro\core\ui\systems.py", line 375, in poll
    return len(graswald.gsystems) and graswald.active.get_gsettings(context)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\3.0\scripts\addons\Graswald-Pro\core\data\gsystem.py", line 103, in get_gsettings
    context.scene.graswald.gsettings[self.gsettings_id_int]
KeyError: 'bpy_prop_collection[key]: key "17" not found'

location: <unknown location>:-1
Python: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\3.0\scripts\addons\Graswald-Pro\core\ui\systems.py", line 324, in poll
    return len(graswald.gsystems) and graswald.active.get_gsettings(context)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\3.0\scripts\addons\Graswald-Pro\core\data\gsystem.py", line 103, in get_gsettings
    context.scene.graswald.gsettings[self.gsettings_id_int]
KeyError: 'bpy_prop_collection[key]: key "17" not found'

location: <unknown location>:-1
```

Comment: Are you using the most recent version of Graswald? Or dare I say it, a cracked version? In general, if it works, don't worry.

Comment: No I purchased the add-on :) But that might be it... I have not had the problem with blender 2.93. I'm going to check for updates. thanks!

Comment: What a wall of text